# Как получить количество img тегов на странице?

Tags: php, javascript, html

На стороне клиента или на стороне сервера решать?

Comment: вам виднее, на чьей стороне надо решать. На стороне клиента сложности не представляет.

Comment: Как посчитать сколько у меня колёс на машине? Это надо в моём гараже смотреть или на заводе спрашивать?

Answer (score 3):

```js
console.log(
document.images.length,
document.querySelectorAll('img').length,
document.getElementsByTagName('img').length
);
```

```html
<img />
<img />
<img />
<img />
```